# Find the basis of a polynomial vector space where the derivative(pi)=0

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working in the $P_3$ space.

Let ***W*** = {*p*($t$) $\in P_3$: *p*'($\pi$) = 0}

and need to find the basis for ***W***

What I've done so far:

*p*($t$) = a$t^3$ + b$t^2$ + c$t$ + $d$

*p*'($t$) = 3a$t^2$ + 2b$t$ + $c$

*p*'($pi$) = $3a(\pi$)$^2$$ + 2b(\pi$) + $c$ = 0, so $c$ = - $3a(\pi$)$^2$$ - 2b(\pi$)

then *p*($t$) = a$t^3$ + b$t^2$ - $3at$$^2$$ - 2bt$ + $d$ = a$t^3$ - $3at$$^2$$ + b$t$^2$ - 2$bt$ + $d$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polynomial $p(t)$ satisfies $p(\pi) = 0$ iff $(t-\pi) \mid p(t)$. In other words, $p \in W$ iff
$$
p'(t) = (t-\pi)(at +b)
$$
So try to find $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that
$$
p_1'(t) = t(t-\pi), \text{ and } p_2'(t) = (t-\pi)
$$
then check that they form a basis for $W$ together with $p_3 = 1$

Comment: The condition is that the *derivative* is zero at $\pi$, not the original function.

Comment: @T.Bongers : Thanks. Mis-read the question. Edited the answer.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I can't. Can you give me another hint?

Comment: @n8sty : Edited my post with another hint.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I don't get where you're getting these at all. Could you give me some more hints?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: He is suggesting that a and b are 1. You just need to find the antiderivatives. Also, you might want a=6, b=2 for aesthetics.